# Check if call result is undefined

Tags: scala.js

how can I check if the result to call a JavaScript function is undefined?

I tried with

```
if( s.getNode(id1) != js.undefined)
```

but fastOptJS say:

> scala.scalajs.js.Dynamic and scala.scalajs.js.UndefOr[Nothing] are
>   unrelated: they will most likely always compare unequal

TIA

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is Scala's type system being a bit "too" helpful.

To compare against `undefined`, you can use `js.isUndefined`:

```
if (!js.isUndefined(s.getNode(id1)))
```

Comment: Thanks very much. Where is it documented? I can see it in http://www.scala-js.org/api/scalajs-library/0.6.2/#scala.scalajs.js.package

Comment: Now it's documented here ;-) If you think there is a logical place to document this, besides the API, we can add it. But it seems like a "troubleshooting" kind of documentation, for which an SO entry is likely to be the best documentation ever.

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to say I can't see it in .... If it is in the documentation I can't find it but that is my problem them. Thanks

Comment: On the very page you mention: http://www.scala-js.org/api/scalajs-library/0.6.2/index.html#scala.scalajs.js.package@isUndefined%28v:Any%29:Boolean

Comment: Sorry, my eyes problem. Thanks for all